# IntelliJ - Spring Boot Runconfiguration with Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, spring-boot, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I'm trying to cofigure a runconfiguration with IntelliJ where I can build my Angular application to the `src/main/resources/public` folder and then start the Spring Boot application serving the frontend and backend in one click.
I used a Spring Boot run configuration in IntelliJ set my main class and added a NPM script before launching the actual Spring Boot application. But somehow I then get a "white label" error message despite the `index.html` file being in the `src/main/resources/public` folder.

EDIT: I have all my other Spring Boot run configurations (microservices) registered as services, so I can start and stop them together easier. The angular frontend microservice should be part of them.

[image: Spring Microservices Run Configurations]

Has anybody an idea how to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in one of my personal projects. There is a maven plugin which loads the NPM modules without you having to worry about it. This plugin can build your Angular application alongside your Spring Boot backend.

Have a look at here: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: This plugin does nothing more than the NPM run configuration I had. But I want to use the Spring Boot run configuration type explicitly. Please see my edits in the original post.